# CodeIginiter routes Issues

Tags: codeigniter

I want to put all my admin views in admin and want to put all my role specific views in other folders. But When I want to access all these views what should I do for that. please provide me help. I have all my views outside views folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->view('admin/view-name');
$this->load->view('other-folder-name/view-name');
```

is this what you're looking ??

Comment: Yes but I have my folder that is not in the views folder. I have the following directory structure,
->Administrator->all admin views here
->Applications->controllers->admin->genral , where genral is my controller in which I want to load vies from Administrator folder.

Comment: Why do you want to keep your views in other folder ??

Comment: rather you can move the Administrator folder inside applications

Comment: That is client requirements. thats why I am moving it there. and also the clients wants to move controller folder as will